# scale multiple textures

Tags: materials, node-editor, scale, mathematics

is there anyway to scale multiple texture nodes? for example the image below. Is there anyway to scale these three textures together? 
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are wanting to keep their scales relative you could use the math node and multiply each scale value by a factor. For example below, I am doubling the scale of each texture, where the first math node is my factor (highlighted in yellow), and each of the next math nodes are my scale of each texture. Just change the factor in the first math node to adjust all three.

[image]

Comment: Using a *Value* Input Node might make it clearer